# How to set datetime format in form_input in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to add datetime format in form_input

I want datetime in this format 2018-09-10 17:05:18
but currently values comes like this 23-09-2018 17:05:18

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to do. Use `date()` and `strtotime()` to get your desire format

```
$date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now')); //Current Date and time
```

**Output**

```
2019-01-05 13:01:20
```

If value is in variable use like this

```
<?php echo form_input('start_date',  (isset($_POST['start_date']) ? date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['start_date'])) : ""), 'class="form-control  datetime" id="start_date" autocomplete="off"'); ?>
```